# Dual boot Windows 11 and Debian 11

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I tried to dual install Windows 11 and Debian 11. I have had already installed Windows 11. Then, following this tutorial
https://linuxhint.com/dual-boot-debian-windows/
I shranked a part of disk (30 Gib). Then, I've installed Debian from a usb stick (but I had here a live if it matters). I unplagged USB and restarted. Nothing happened. My windows started as usual, there wasn't GRUB to choose what to start. In disk managment, Windows shows space for Linux shich I created unalocated. What should I do?

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? Can you boot directly from UEFI boot menu? Some vendors (HP &) UEFI only change boot order from UEFI system settings. Some (Acer &) require you to enable trust. What brand/model system?

Comment: Both installed in UEFI boot mode. No, I can't boot debian from UEFI (I didn't see it, only Windows). I have Lenovo V330-14IKB

Comment: It should be a grub entry. Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I just remembered that it haven't asked me abiut where to install grub. Can I somehow check was system installed and maybe somehow install grub? Or I should just try to install again from usb?

Comment: If new install, you can do another install, be sure to use same partition(s). Or if install is otherwise ok, you can use Boot-Repair to install grub.